# Как отрендерить дочерние компоненты в VueJS?

Tags: vue.js

Есть компонент `Comp1`, который может принимать в себя любые компоненты в любом порядке и количестве.

```
<Comp1>
  <div>Content</div>
  <span>Content</span>
  <SomeComp/>
</Comp1>
```

Внутри себя он должен обрабатывать каждый дочерний компонент и выводить его.

Пример вывода:

```
<Comp1>
  <div>
    <div>Content</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Content</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <SomeComp/>
  </div>
</Comp1>
```

Как можно это реализовать в VueJS?

Comment: Ваша задача очень специфична, немогли бы вы дать больше контекста, какую проблему этим решением Вы хотите решить?

Comment: Нужно делать обертку над каждым дочерним компонентом, причем с возможностью делать это рекурсивно. В данном случае компонент Comp1 будет таблицей, а каждый дочерний компонент будет обернут в <tr> а каждый его дочерний компонент в <td> и т. д., если потребуется.

Comment: А React это делается очень просто с помощью итерации props.chindren, причем такие вещи встречаются в нем повсеместно. Хотелось бы иметь не готовый плагин, а хотя бы ссылку на документацию Vue, как это можно сделать. В документации пока что ничего не нашел. Хотелось бы делать это без передачи пропров, а в таком стиле, как я описал в вопросе. А поскольку React и Vue решают одни и те же задачи, наверное, оба должны уметь работать с этим...

Answer (score 0):

> По моему личному мнению, данный патерн нужно использовать с крайней осторожностью, он не расширяем верятнее будет правильнее использовать `v-for` и явно обернуть каждое значение в тег.

Как Вы верно заметили в обсуждении, в реакте это делается давольно просто. Чтож Vue не запрещает использование JSX. Comp1 будет выглядеть так

```js
<script>
    export default {
        name: "Comp1",
        props: {
            tag: {
                type: [String, Object],
                default: "div"
            },
            
            wrapper: {
                type: [String, Object],
                default: "div"
            }
        },
        
        render (createElement) {
            return createElement(
                this.tag,
                this.$slots.default.map(
                    el => createElement(this.wrapper, [el])
                )
            )
        }
    };
</script>
```

Здесь у нас есть два пропса, первый `tag` задает тег который будет ипользоваться вместо самого компонета, второй `wrapper` будет использоваться для оберток.
Например

```
<Comp1 tag="ul" wrapper="li"></Comp1>
```

создаст список из значений переданных в `Comp1`.

Так же можно использовать дугие компонеты как обертки, если они реализуют собственный слот.

```
<Comp1 tag="ul" :wrapper="CompWithSlot"></Comp1>
```